# How can i make this application use the current textbox value, which is the number of clicks, change the image in the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created this application and right now when it runs i get the textbox value increasing with each click which i want.

the nested divs are also created with an image placed into the inner most div. how can i get that image to change between two images using the value from the textbox?
So if the value in the textbox is = an odd number because i clicked the button 1 time it shows image1.jpg and if the value in the textbox is = any even number is shows image2.jpg

I only need the nested divs to appear on the first click and have the image change with everyclick, using the vlue in the textbox to make that happen.

I was going to use a boolean but it has to use the value in the textbox. i know I have
not made that var global so maybe that is what i am having trouble with. idk if it goes into the addbutterfly function or the function used with the button. lots of help needed at the end of this application

```js
var i = 0;
function runTogether1() 
  {
      addDiv();
      addDiv2();
      addDiv3();
      addbutterfly();
      incrementValue();
  }

function addDiv() 
  {
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.classList.add('div1');
    document.body.appendChild(div1);
  }

function addDiv2() 
  {
    var div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.classList.add('div2');
    document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[i].appendChild(div2);
  }

function addDiv3() 
  {
    var div3 = document.createElement('div');
    div3.classList.add('div3');
    document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[i].appendChild(div3);
  }

function addbutterfly() 
{
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "bfly1.gif";
document.getElementsByClassName("div3")[i].appendChild(img);
i++;
}

function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('id1').value = value;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src ="bflyjs.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="button">
      <button onclick = "runTogether1()"> 
          click to get nested divs
      </button>  
      <textarea id ="id1"> 
      </textarea>
    </div>
 </body>
  <style>
    .div1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: limegreen;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}


div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}


</style
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Let me see if I got you right. Whenever the button is clicked and the textarea value is and odd number, image 1 (bfly1.gif) must be added; otherwise, when the value is an even number, image 2 (bfly2.gif) must be added. Is that right?

Comment: yes that is correct! any advice on how to make that happen using the value in the textarea?

Comment: `img.src = \`bfly${2-i%2}.gif\`;` you can use the [modulus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) of the value

Answer (score 1):

The function `addbutterfly()` is the one responsible to add the image, so you can get the value of the `textfield` inside of it.

As you know the current value, it is possible to use it the way you want. In this case, it should look something like this:

```js
function addbutterfly() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');

  // Get the value of the "textfield"
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);

  // If the value is even, add "bfly2.gif", otherwhise add "bfly1.gif"
  img.src = value % 2 === 0 ? "bfly2.gif" : "bfly1.gif";

  document.getElementsByClassName("div3")[i].appendChild(img);
  i++;
}
```